# Shifting button text to another button when it clicked

Tags: java, android

I wanna change button text when it is clicked.For example if "4" clicked I should replace with empty button text and . I wanna make Puzzle game with numbers. I come across the problem when button clicked it should shift button's text.

[image]

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonsContainer = findViewById(R.id.buttonsContainer);
    restartButton = findViewById(R.id.restartButton);
    restartButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        LinearLayout rows = (LinearLayout) buttonsContainer.getChildAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            buttons[i][j] = (Button) rows.getChildAt(j);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
        numberList.add(i);
    }
    restartGame();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.restartButton: {
            restartGame();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.buttonsContainer:{
            changePlace();
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void restartGame() {
    Collections.shuffle(numberList);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if(i==3 && j==3)continue;
            buttons[i][j].setText(String.valueOf(numberList.get(4*i+j)));
        }
    }
}

private void changePlace(){

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I wanna read an actual question

Comment: I wanna make Puzzle game with numbers

Comment: to shift button's text with another button's text

Comment: So, when you press 8 (in the picture), what happens?

Comment: Nothing But when pressed 4 or 14 I should replace with empty text

Comment: Then, the rule is only valid for 4 and 14?

Comment: No I should shift button's text with diagonal direction

Comment: If it is the game I used to play when I was a child (made with physical sliding tiles), there's no diagonal direction.

Comment: Yes like that I mean it's change only with diagonal button's text

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it as shown :

```
Button bn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.RegiB);
bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
        bn.setText("");//it will replace text with empty
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to achieve but changing the text of a button is pretty simple. Just call `setText()` in `OnClickListener()`.

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            button.setText("_Text you want to change_");
        }
    });
```